# How to to continue update texview on countdown timer running on background?

Tags: android, textview, updating

I have this countdown timer which i modified to count up.The timer will keep on running at the same time give percentage on a textview (tvp). below are the code.

```
   timer = new CountUpTimer(date3) {
        public void onTick(int secondt) {
            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("HH:mm:ss");
            tv_timer.setText(simpleDateFormat.format (secondt));
            t1 = date3 - date;
            percentage = Math.round (secondt/t1 *100);
            tvp.setText ( percentage+"%" );

        }
    };timer.start();
```

The timer is running on background which i use services and broadcast receiver and it work just fine.
The problem is, the percentage textview is not updating and running and stuck on the last value after pressing back button. below are the runnable code used to update percentage textview.

```
  getActivity ().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tvp.setText ( percentage + "%" );
        }
    });
```

below are my timer service code

```
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    mpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    mEditor = mpref.edit();

    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 5, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    intent = new Intent(str_receiver);


}

class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mHandler.post( () -> {
            timerprogressupdate ();
        } );
    }

}

public String timerprogressupdate() {

    fn_update ( IFTimer.secondt );
    fn_updatep ( IFTimer.percentage );

    return timerprogressupdate();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("Service finish","Finish");


}

private void fn_update(long str_time){

    intent.putExtra("time",str_time);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

broadcast receiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String strDate = intent.getStringExtra("time");

    }
};
```

I need the percentage textview updating and running after i press back button. Anyone have a solution on this? Appreciated if anyone could help me.

Comment: Hi there dude. Maybe you can put code of your service and your broadcast, and the action of back button. Still, if u exit of the activity and return to it later the components in your UI maybe can be update, you need use onRestart to begin set values tu textView

Comment: Hi bro. the textview is updated the last value of the percentage but not increasing based on the millisecond running on the countdown timer. My countdown timer actually still running after back button and after return to it but not the percentage.

Comment: Well, It isn't possible update one view in background, onResume() would be the best approach. But if u use one broadcast u can registerReceiver when activity is showing (onCreate, onResume) and unregisterReceiver (onPause).. then u are shure that u a getting the right values... but sorry, maybe i can be wrong, i need see more code to make one answer.

Comment: bro i have updated my service and broadcast code. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: bro i figured it out. The problem is the timer is not running on service. I put the timer running on service and the problem solved. Thanks for the support bro.